# Is it possible to limit allowed JRuby commands in a Java application?

Tags: java, security, jruby

I use JRuby in my Java application to allow users to run their scripts. The set of operations needed for normal function of the application is not big. The script should control some variables in Java code and change the process during the execution.

So I want to have an opportunity to limit the number of allowed operations. Say, I don't want the users have an access to the file system.

```
f = File.new("myfile.txt", "w") 
f.puts( "Hello!" ) 
f.close
```

This should be forbidden.

How can I do such a setting? The only idea I have is to parse the user-script before the launch and to compare the script with white list of allowed operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is create a white list of allowed commands.  If a script is found to contain a command that is not in the white list you need to reject the entire script.  A security manager as Andrew Thompson points out is a good extra layer, but it is not the end of the security layering.  I don't think running in a sandboxed applet is really going to buy you that much, since you still have to determine if the script was valid to begin with.

**WHITE LIST EXAMPLE**

Typically when you generate a white list there are a limited number of options/commands you want users to be able to choose from and the rest become discarded.  you would create some enumeration or final data structure (to minimize its ability to be modified during runtime by malicious programs).    If you wanted users to only have the option to invoke your function `foo` and not `bar` you could write something like this, which is completely primitive but illustrates the concept:

```
class WhiteList  
{  
     allowedCommands = ["foo"];  
}
```

and in your main something like this:

```
class Main  
{  
     for(Command command in userInput)  
     { 
           if(command not in allowedCommands)  
           {  
                log security message;  
                continue/break
           }  
     }  
}
```

Comment: The standard `SecurityManager` might not be enough (e.g especially for resource usage - what if the client script sends the JRE into an infinite loop?).  Such extra precautions make good sense.

Comment: The idea of a white list is great! Could you please give me some tips or urls, what is meant by "white list" in this certain case? Can it be done by a supported function of JRuby or should I implement it by myself at the level of parsing the script as a text? I have found an example of a white list for Rye. It would be greate to have something like this for JRuby (https://github.com/delano/rye/blob/master/lib/rye/cmd.rb) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install a [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html)<sup>1</sup> for the user code.  Or even easier, run the code from a sand-boxed applet or [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) launched application.

1. > The security manager is a class that allows applications to implement a security policy. It allows an application to determine, before performing a possibly unsafe or sensitive operation, what the operation is and whether it is being attempted in a security context that allows the operation to be performed. The application can allow or disallow the operation.

Answer (score 0):

JRuby allows you to define a [Profile](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Profile.java) that lets you intercept certain methods. You can call `setProfile` on a `org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer`. Your problem is most probably solved by a combination of this and a Java [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html).

Alternatively, you may want to look at it as a Ruby problem, instead of a Java problem:

- [Shikashi](http://tario.github.io/shikashi/doc/) is a Ruby sandbox that lets you intercept calls. [Evalhook](https://github.com/tario/evalhook/) is at its core that, basically, lets `eval` Ruby code and intercept every outing call.